# Where is the config for redis-cli?

Tags: 18.04, redis

I have installed redis client (without the server) on one of my servers:

```
sudo apt install redis-tools
```

I would like to use redis-cli to connect to a central server where redis is installed.

But because I didn't install the server, there is no config file available at this path:

```
/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Is there a way to create the config, so I don't have to use `-h` every time?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Redis, but from package point of view this package does not have files in `/etc` - see https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/redis-tools/filelist .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know creating the server's config file on your machine (the server running client tools) doesn't do anything.

Instead of using:

```
redis-cli -h host -p port -a password
```

Create an alias:

```
alais rediscli='redis-cli -h host -p port -a password'
```

Add it to your `.bash_aliases` or `.bashrc` to make it permanent:

```
echo "alais rediscli='redis-cli -h host -p port -a password'" >> .bash_aliases
```

`.bash_aliases` will get sourced automatically by `.bashrc`.

No you only have to run:

```
rediscli
```